# Angular js with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Is there a way to automate writing Jasmine test cases for Angular Js code in windows?

I have tried using the npm package but have got errors everytime. Is anyone aware of a step by step process.

Comment: how do you mean automate writing Jasmine test cases? You should write test cases as a developer, it won't write itself.

Comment: There is an option using npm package I guess that it will automatically generate test cases for controller atleast covering 40-50%, but I am not able to configure it for windows.

Comment: I'm sure those test cases are not proper test cases. Since it's not something u can automate.

Comment: U can maybe generate the wireframe but you have to implement the details inside I guess.

Comment: Hey check out this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-yosapy, this is for controller test case generation. If it works we would just have to write test cases for services.

Comment: But I am unable to configure the above for windows. If anyone has worked with it please help me.